# What is a sealer and what is the difference between Ethhash, NoProof and BasicAuthority sealers?

Tags: blockchain, cpp-ethereum

Default sealer in cpp-ethereum is `NoProof`:

https://github.com/ethereum/cpp-ethereum/blob/43bae2c78e2a968ef4eb37bec2da4d9b85fa2392/libethcore/ChainOperationParams.h#L73

But I don't understand what is sealer in the first place, and what are differences between `Ethhash`, `NoProof` and `BasicAuthority` sealers.